# Overload template function

Tags: c++, templates

Inside a member function of a template class, I need a compare that works for int, float and string. My solution is to let the member function (DFA::entry) use a selfmade comp function:(template < class T, class U> int comp(T s_one, U s_two)).

The problem now is that after compiling, when the programm starts. I get a exception thrown for a access violation when trying to write at a position 0x00000004.

I only put in the parts of my code that I think are relevant for the problem, because without the comp function the programm works perfectly fine (but just for int).

Is this the right way to let a template member function use a non-member template function?

```
#define EPSILON 0.9

//Forward and non-member-Function Declarations
template< class dto_s, class dto_ea, int nQ, int nSigma, int nF > class DFA;

template <class T, class U>
int comp(T s_one, U s_two) {
    int ret_val = 0;
    if (s_two > s_two)
    {
        ret_val = ((s_two - s_one) < EPSILON);
    }
    if (s_one > s_two)
    {
        ret_val = ((s_one - s_two) < EPSILON);
    }
    return ret_val;
}

inline int comp(std::string s_one, std::string s_two) {
    //return abs(s_one.compare(s_two));
    return (s_one == s_two);
}



//Class Definition
template< class dto_s, class dto_ea, int nQ, int nSigma, int nF > class DFA
{
public:
    int entry(dto_ea[]);

    //Returns index of entry in Sigma
    int entry_to_number(dto_ea);
    //Returns index of state in Q
    int state_to_number(dto_s);

private:
    std::array<dto_s, nQ> Q;
    std::array<dto_ea, nSigma> Sigma;
    std::array<dto_s, nQ * nSigma> Delta;
    std::array<dto_s, nF> F;

    dto_s* current_state;
};


//              ENTRY FUNCTION
template<class dto_s, class dto_ea, int nQ, int nSigma, int nF>
inline int DFA<dto_s, dto_ea, nQ, nSigma, nF>::entry(dto_ea wort[])
{

    dto_s* temp_state = current_state;

    //these 2 functions work correctly and return a int
    row = state_to_number(*temp_state);
    column = entry_to_number(wort[i]);


    for (auto i = Q.begin(); i != Q.end(); i++)
    {
        if (comp<dto_s, dto_s>(Delta[row * nSigma, column], (*i))) {
            //do something
        }
    }
    for (auto i = F.begin(); i != F.end(); i++)
    {
        if (comp<dto_s, dto_s>((*temp_state), (*i))) {
            //do something
        }
    }


    return return_code;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the crash and locate where in your code it happens.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: That's not a valid comparison function for floats, because it's not a partial order (in particular, it doesn't satisfy transitivity: you can have a, b, and c such that a compares equivalent to b and b compares equivalent to c, but a doesn't compare equivalent to c.) You cannot use your comparison with things like `std::map` or `std::sort` or `std::binary_search`.

Secondly, you're comparing `s_two` against `s_two`, when I think you meant to compare it against `s_one`. So that's gonna cause problems too.

Again, though, this comparison is already fatally flawed. A valid comparison for floats is `a < b`. Mucking about with "epsilons" is the wrong solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve with them.